# If text is in cell, with multiple if's

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to fill a new column in with a gender based on what is in the title of the item in the first column.

For example:

> Column E2 - Adidas Essentials Kids Small Bag Shoulder Black Blue
>   Column F2 (Auto filled with formala) - Kids
>
> Column E3 - Adidas Mens Bay & Main Jumper Hoodie Grey   Column F3
>   (Auto filled with formala) - Mens

```
=IF(SEARCH("Mens",E2),"Mens",IF(SEARCH("Womens",E2),"Womens",IF(SEARCH("Kids",E2),"Kids","Unisex"))
```

This is the formula in F I've tried but it's only matching Mens, and even when it finds nothing it's not defaulting to the final "Unisex"

Comment: Your data structure is confusing. What is in E2?

Comment: Sorry, updated OP. E2 is the item title and E3 is the formula cell to deduce the gender

Comment: Think about "mens" it turns up in "Mens" AND in "Womens" ... you need to think...

Comment: I did not realize "Kids" was a gender...but I can roll with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+99,SEARCH({"Mens","Womens","Kids"},A1),{"Mens","Womens","Kids"}),"Unisex")
```

Data:

[image: Data]

Comment: will the search for "mens" also find the "mens" in "womens"?

Comment: @SolarMike Updated. Well spotted.

Comment: Just a detail - the value on error should be "unisex".

Comment: @M.Douda Seems you read the question a lot better than I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the SEARCH() formulas in ISNUMBER() formulas to get the proper test.

Here's an example of the formula:

[image]

You formula does not work because the result of the first SEARCH() is an error if the text in it is not in the text that you're checking.

Note that you should switch around the order of womens and mens in your conditionals, because the string `Mens` is found in `Womens` and therefore `Womens` be detected as masculine and flow will not proceed to the next IF.

Answer (score 0):

This works, notice that I check for "women" before "mens", not done kids, but you can expand as needed.

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("womens",A1,1)>0,0),"Womens",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("mens",A1,1)>0,0),"Mens","check"))
```

[image]